# RTSP/1.0 459 Aggregate operation not allowed

Tags: rtsp, rtsp-client

I'm working to rtsp .I want to develop android by rtsp. 
The rtsp server is VLC.
The client is java.
I reveive "RTSP/1.0 459 Aggregate operation not allowed" when I send "SETUP";

My Code Example:

```
DESCRIBE rtsp://192.168.0.196:8554/test.sdp RTSP/1.0
Cseq: 2


return content：
RTSP/1.0 200 OK
Server: VLC/2.1.0
Date: Fri, 29 Nov 2013 04:14:13 GMT
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Base: rtsp://192.168.0.196:8554/test.sdp
Content-Length: 742
Cache-Control: no-cache
Cseq: 2

v=0
o=- 15439064194650748030 15439064194650748030 IN IP4 WIN-AF6P80LVIJ0
s=Unnamed
i=N/A
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
t=0 0
a=tool:vlc 2.1.0
a=recvonly
a=type:broadcast
a=charset:UTF-8
a=control:rtsp://192.168.0.196:8554/test.sdp
m=audio 0 RTP/AVP 96
b=RR:0
a=rtpmap:96 mpeg4-generic/44100/2
a=fmtp:96 streamtype=5; profile-level-id=15; mode=AAC-hbr; config=12100000000000000000000000000000; SizeLength=13; IndexLength=3; IndexDeltaLength=3; Profile=1;
a=control:rtsp://192.168.0.196:8554/test.sdp/trackID=0
m=video 0 RTP/AVP 96
b=RR:0
a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000
a=fmtp:96 packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=640028;sprop-parameter-sets=Z2QAKKy0A8ARPywgAAB9IAAXcAHjBlQ=,aO48sA==;
a=control:rtsp://192.168.0.196:8554/test.sdp/trackID=1

SETUP rtsp://192.168.0.196:8554/test.sdp RTSP/1.0
Cseq: 3
Transport: RTP/AVP;UNICAST;client_port=16264-16265


return content：
RTSP/1.0 459 Aggregate operation not allowed
Server: VLC/2.1.0
Date: Fri, 29 Nov 2013 04:14:19 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Cache-Control: no-cache
Cseq: 3


return error：RTSP/1.0 459 Aggregate operation not allowed
Server: VLC/2.1.0
Date: Fri, 29 Nov 2013 04:14:19 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Cache-Control: no-cache
Cseq: 3
```

I want to solve it,thank you!

Answer (score 2):

the SETUP request is used to setup a rtp/rtcp connection pair, that is dedicated to ONLY ONE stream (ex. the video track, or one audio track).
When you issue a SETUP you are specifying two ports that you will use for rtp and rtcp.
if the presentation has more than one stream (like in your case) you must issue a SETUP request for every stream you want to receive, and open two ports for each. In your case the media file has one audio and one video stream, so you must issue a SETUP for `rtsp://192.168.0.196:8554/test.sdp/trackID=0`
and one for `rtsp://192.168.0.196:8554/test.sdp/trackID=1.`
The `trackID=X` parts are the ones included in the sdp description that the server returns, under the `"a=control:"` attributes.